# Facebook API PHP - post to live feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post to users page feed / wall and instead of my posts stored at the "Posts to page" section as embedded posts.

Here is my code:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
            $this->session,
            'POST',
            '/' . $page_id.'/feed',
            array (
                'message' => $msg,
                'link' => $link,
                'id' => $page_id,
                'published' => true
            )
        );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

        return $graphObject;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a User Token, you need to use a Page Token. Information about all the Tokens and how to get them can be found in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

This is how it works:

1. Authorize User with `manage_pages` and `publish_actions`
2. Call `/me/accounts` to get a list of all your Pages including their Page Tokens

You can also get an Extended Page Token that is valid forever by using an Extended User token for the call to `/me/accounts`.